# Cast from Pointer to Pointer C++

Tags: c++, casting

would appreciate if I get pointer to following line of code

```
Char fileName[100] ;

strncpy(static_cast<Char *>( fileName),static_cast<const Char *>(getCurrentUser()),Int32(ML_STRING_SIZE));
```

I get Lint error: Cast from Pointer to Pointer. If I cast without static it throws error as C-style cast. If I do not use any cast

```
strncpy(( fileName),(getCurrentUser()),Int32(ML_STRING_SIZE));   it throws 
array type passed to function expecting a pointer
```

I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: What is `Char` defined as ? What is the type of `fileName` ? And do you really need the second cast ? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: type of  `fileName`??

Comment: Char is typedef of char.

Comment: In that case you should not even need any casts (unless `fileName` is `const`, in which case you have a much bigger problem).

Comment: What errors/warnings do you get with just `strncat(fileName, "_", ML_STRING_SIZE);`, if any ?

Comment: updated the question. I get  array type passed to function expecting a pointer

Comment: Any particular reason you're using functions like `strncat` in C++?

Comment: What if you pass `&fileName[0]` instead of just `fileName`? A harsh linter...

Comment: Thanks dreamlax.. posted the answer

Comment: Don't use `strncpy` until you've **read** and **understood** its documentation. It is **not** a "safe" dropin replacement for `strcpy`. If you've screwed up your string length, this use of `strncpy` merely postpones the buffer overrun. It does not prevent it.

Comment: You could jump through hoops and use `std::decay` (c++11) to appease the linter. Although I don't see why the linter should highlight this as an issue. It sounds overly pedantic to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix.

```
strncpy(( &fileName[0]),(getCurrentUser()),UInt32(ML_STRING_SIZE));
```

1. First agrument &fileName[0]  ++ DreamLax
2. Second argument returns const char* so no need to cast
3. Third argument should be unsigned int.

All three together solved the issue.

Comment: @user2079303: It's not the compiler that is complaining, it is a linter.